# Problema con el entorno de desarrollo de react

Tags: reactjs

estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de arrancar con react, he instalado node y yarn y a la hora de arrcancar el Visual Studio me tira el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe a que se que puede ser?
Gracias.

Comment: Estas iniciando la aplicación dentro del directorio del proyecto? Que comando est´s usando? es un proyecto nuevo o lo has clonado?

Comment: Tuve que formatear la pc, supongo que tenia algunos problemas con las variables de entorno.